# Lucene and Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, lucene

I'm trying to port an existing web application into AppEngine, however it have some dependencies with Lucence. For those who have worked with Lucence-AppEngine will these package work out of the box with AppEngine:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.TermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
```

If so, which specific version.

Comment: Just to throw it out there, have you taken a look at [this lucene-appengine project](https://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine/)?

Comment: Ok I see, so you mean I just need to replace these packages with the packages of Lucene-AppEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they will. I was using these before the advent of the full text Search API. I would use Lucene to parse and tokenize an entity fields into keywords and store them into an indexed property list on the entity. But this had severe limitations.

I am just now porting my keyword search to the Search API and it is really a joy.

Just beware that you will most probably get some startup exceptions when running unit tests with LocalServiceTestHelper if you keep your own Lucene jars on the classpath. I will assume that the Search API expects or relies on a specific version of Lucene and its dependencies. If your Lucene jars are loaded instead of the ones from the GAE environment, expect some issues.

Good luck!